# C compile error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

Tags: c, declaration

When I try to compile my code I get three errors all stating
"error: expected declaration or statement at end of input"
All pointing to the same line. The line changes depending on sections that I have commented out. The least amount of code I can leave still in the function while still getting the error is the declaration lines at the top of the function.

All other solutions point to there not being a closed bracket somewhere, but I have searched and cannot find one.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
void get_agents(struct Base* s) {
int count;
char c = 'A'; //temp char declartion
char temp1, temp2;
char *file, *extra, *line;

line = malloc(sizeof(char)*128); 
file = malloc(sizeof(char)*256); 
extra = malloc(sizeof(char)*256); 

s->agentfile = fopen(s->agentfilename, "r");
while (c != EOF) {
    fgets(line,500,s->agentfile);
    c = line[0]; //gets first char from line
    if (c != '#') {
        struct Agent* newAge = malloc(sizeof(struct Agent));
        struct Agent* agentNum = malloc(sizeof(struct Agent));

        newAge->next = 0; 
        sscanf(line, "%d %d %c %s%c%s%c", &newAge->posx, &newAge->posy,
        &newAge->name, file, &temp1, extra, &temp2);

        agentNum = s->start //sets agentNum to the first agent in list
        if (agentNum == NULL) { //does first agent exist?
            s->start = newAge; //first agent in list
        } else {
            while (agentNum->next) { //is this not the last agent?
                agentNum = agentNum->next; //get the next agent
            }
            agentNum->next = newAge; //else, set newagent to be new last
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: malloc returns a void pointer. You need to cast the pointer to (struct Agent *)

Comment: @Vivek No in C don't cast returned address by malloc/calloc

Comment: @vivek void pointer can be assigned to any pointer. In this case cast Not required in C

Comment: @Vivek YES malloc returns void pointer [that is why you should not typecast it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Vivek [read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858) very good answer.

Comment: True dat. Damn C and C++ :P

Comment: @Vivek in C++ don't use malloc/calloc use `new` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

missing `;` before `if()`:

```
agentNum = s->start ;
                    ^
   if (agentNum == NULL) { //doe
```

Comment: That has "fixed" the error thank you. But now I'm getting the same error (3 times) on line 123. Which is the second half of the long sscanf line

Comment: @user2809725 try writing `sscanf` in same line (don't split), I am not sure but I don't find any other place...

Comment: I have attempted that and the error just moves to the full line, which is then 122

Answer (score 2):

```
   agentNum = s->start //sets agentNum to the first agent in list
```

No  `;` (semicolon) at the end of statement.

Add  `;` (semicolon) at the end of statement

```
agentNum = s->start ; //sets agentNum to the first agent in list 
                    ^
```